# Derive an equation related to magnetism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, harmonic-oscillator, differentiation, calculus

> Solve the equations for $v_x$ and $v_y$ :
>   $$m\frac{d({v_x)}}{dt} = qv_yB \qquad m\frac{d{(v_y)}}{dt} = -qv_xB$$ 
>   by differentiating them with respect to time to obtain two equations of the form: $$ \frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + \alpha^2u = 0$$ where $u = v_x$ or $v_y$ and $\alpha^2 = qB/m$. 
>   Then show that $u = C\cos{\alpha t}$ and $u = D\sin{\alpha t}$, where C and D are constants, satisfy this equation

Whenever I differentiate the first equation with respect to time, I get a resulting equation with the form: $$ \frac{d^2u}{dt^2} + \alpha^2 \frac{du}{dt} = 0$$

Comment: du/dt = d/dt vx or d/dt vy

Comment: WAS, try again. Start by taking the time derivative of the first equation (left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiating the first equation -

$$
m\ddot v_x = q \dot v_y B \implies m \ddot v_x = - \frac{q^2B^2}{m}v_x \implies  \ddot v_x + \bigg(\frac{qB}{m}\bigg)^2 v_x = 0
$$

Where I have substituted for $\dot v_y$ from equation 2.

You will get a similar equation on differentiation equation 2 for $\ddot v_y$.
And then of course given $\alpha = \frac{qB}{m}$ you can get solutions as -

$$
u = A \cos(\alpha t) + B \sin(\alpha t) \qquad \qquad u = v_x,v_y
$$